# Online virtual machine for malware tests?

Tags: web-apps, virtualization, virtual-machine, malware

I can remember a website that allowed people to upload malware to test it on their virtual machine server.

There was a screenshot of a virtual Windows XP machine, updated every ~5 minutes.

I am however unable to find that website, because I just find Jotta, VirusTotal, etc., but not that website.

Does anyone here know what website I am referring to?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Intezer Analyze](https://analyze.intezer.com) or [ANY.RUN](https://any.run). I don't know so much about Intezer, but ANY.RUN is Freemium. You can use their service but for more features you have to pay.

Comment: You could improve your answer by providing more details on them, including screenshots and feature lists.